# How to use Roslyn generate an array of string literals that are each wrapped in an #if?

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn, directive

## The Use Case

It would be helpful to know at runtime which `#define` symbols were used to build a C# application. Since it doesn't appear to be possible to actually do that, I'm instead using Roslyn to generate an enormous `string[]` with every `#define` I might possibly be interested in listing. Each `#define` should be stored in this array as a `string` literal which itself is only included if the associated symbol is `#define`d, like so:

```cs
// This class is generated, do not change it manually.

public static class DefineSymbols
{
    public static System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<string> Symbols => _symbols;

    private static readonly string[] _symbols = new string[] {
#if DEBUG
        "DEBUG",
#endif
#if UNITY
        "UNITY",
#endif
#if UNITY_ASSERTIONS
        "UNITY_ASSERTIONS",
#endif
        // ...and lots more symbols...
    };
}
```

## The Problem

The easy part is generating a big-ass array of `string` literals. The hard part is placing the commas properly. Using this code...

```cs
private SyntaxNode CreateSymbolsArray(SyntaxGenerator generator, string[] defines)
{
    var stringType = generator.TypeExpression(SpecialType.System_String);

    return generator.FieldDeclaration(
        name: "_symbols",
        type: generator.ArrayTypeExpression(stringType),
        accessibility: Accessibility.Private,
        modifiers: DeclarationModifiers.Static | DeclarationModifiers.ReadOnly,
        initializer: generator.ArrayCreationExpression(
            generator.TypeExpression(SpecialType.System_String),
            defines.Select(d => CreateDefine(generator, d))
        )
    );
}


private SyntaxNode CreateDefine(SyntaxGenerator generator, string define)
{
    var @if = SyntaxFactory.IfDirectiveTrivia(SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression(define), true, true, true);
    var @endif = SyntaxFactory.EndIfDirectiveTrivia(true);

    return generator.LiteralExpression(define)
            .WithLeadingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.Trivia(@if))
            .WithTrailingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.Trivia(@endif))
        ;
}
```

...places commas outside of the `#if`/`#endif` pairs, so the generated code won't compile unless every tested symbol is defined.

```cs
    private static readonly string[] _symbols = new string[] {
#if DEBUG
        "DEBUG"
#endif
    ,
#if UNITY
        "UNITY"
#endif
    ,
#if UNITY_ASSERTIONS
        "UNITY_ASSERTIONS"
#endif
        // ...and lots more symbols...
    };
```

So, here's my question: **How can I ensure the commas are wrapped inside the `#if`/`#endif` pairs just like the `string` literals are?**

Comment: Whats the problem you are trying to solve? And why with Roslyn? Why not with a t4 script?

Comment: How about using a `List<string>`, and for each symbol generate a `list.Add("literal");` between #if-#endif?

Comment: @LegacyCode All of this code exists within a plugin for an existing code generator powered by Roslyn.

Comment: @PeterB Unless there's something I'm not understanding about your suggestion, that's already what I'm doing (but with LINQ).

Comment: I meant it like this: `private static readonly string[] _symbols = GetSymbols();` followed by a method `private static string[] GetSymbols() { ... }` with a method body that creates a `List<string>` followed by Roslyn-generated `#if ... list.Add("literal"); #endif` blocks, which in the end returns `list.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [Roslyn Quoter](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/), I figured it out! Roslyn Quoter is a tool that lets you enter a C# snippet and see what API calls you'd need to generate it.

Providing Roslyn Quoter my original code sample returns a snippet that's too long to post verbatim. It was useful in helping me write something simpler and more concise, however.

**TLDR:** To solve my exact problem, you need to provide everything as a sequence of `SyntaxTrivia` nodes that leads a closing-brace token (`}`).

---

Here are some more details. I created three `SyntaxTrivia` nodes for each `#define` symbol:

1. The `#if` directive
2. The `string` literal, as a piece of disabled text (which is fine, because the disabled text itself is simple)
3. The `#endif` directive

Here's what that looks like:

```cs
using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory;

// ...later, within the actual class...

private SyntaxTrivia[] CreateDefine(string define)
{
    return new[]
    {
        Trivia(
            IfDirectiveTrivia(
                IdentifierName(define),
                true,
                false,
                false
            )
        ), // # if MY_DEFINE
        DisabledText($"        \"{define}\",\n"),  // "MY_DEFINE",
        Trivia(EndIfDirectiveTrivia(true)),  // #endif
    };
}

/* Output looks like this:
#if MY_DEFINE
        "MY_DEFINE",
#endif
*/
```

After that, the tricky part is the array initialization expression. Here's how I did that.

The tricky part after that is putting everything in an initializer expression, which in practice looks like an empty array initializer with a *lot* of leading trivia. Here's how I did that:

```cs
using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory;

// ...later, within the actual class...

private SyntaxNode CreateDefinesArrayInitializerExpression(string[] defines)
{
    var stringType = PredefinedType(Token(SyntaxKind.StringKeyword)); // string
    var arrayType = ArrayType(stringType)
        .WithRankSpecifiers(
            SingletonList(
                ArrayRankSpecifier(
                    SingletonSeparatedList<ExpressionSyntax>(
                        OmittedArraySizeExpression()
                    )
                ) // []
            )
        )
    ; // string[]

    return ArrayCreationExpression(arrayType) // new
        .WithInitializer(
            InitializerExpression(SyntaxKind.ArrayInitializerExpression) // string[] {
                .WithCloseBraceToken(
                    Token(
                        TriviaList(defines.SelectMany(CreateDefine)), // <all the #defines>
                        SyntaxKind.CloseBraceToken, // }
                        TriviaList() // <nothing>
                    )
                 )
        )
        .WithSemicolonToken(Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)) // ;
    ;
}

/* Output looks like this:
new string[] {
#if DEBUG
        "DEBUG"
#endif
    ,
#if UNITY
        "UNITY"
#endif
    ,
#if UNITY_ASSERTIONS
        "UNITY_ASSERTIONS"
#endif
    };
*/
```

It's verbose, but you can write some extension methods to help; I did, but I omitted them to simplify copy-pasting. There might even be a NuGet package full of them floating around somewhere.